# Fastest conditional with a lookup in Python

Tags: python

I'm looking at adding some optional logging code to my software.  I expect most of the time it will be disabled, so I am very interested in the fast path.

The usual approach of write it first, then optimize is not as ideal in this situation because the intent of the code is to make logging cheap enough that developers that use my software will be willing to put it into some tight loops that users may wish to explore after release.  Thus, it actually makes sense for me to spend some time optimizing first.

I have been using the timeit module to identify the best path forward.  I have found the most optimal approach is to have a local variable with the flag indicating whether to run the code or not.  The code looks like:

```
flag = logger.shouldLog # loookup the variable once
while True:
   ... do some operations in a tight loop
   if flag:
       logger.log(x, y, z)
```

I'll call this my reference time, so it executes in 1.0 time.

**Question 1:** Is there an even faster way to have conditional logging than this short of writing two functions, one with logging one without?

The alternatives I have looked at involve looking up a variable such as

```
while True:
    ... do some operations
    if logger.shouldLog:
        logger.log(x, y, z)
```

Which runs in about 32.5 time.... much slower because of the lookup

I also looked at how bad a function call made this:

```
while True:
    ... do some operations
    if logger.shouldLog():    # simply returns False in my test case
        logger.log(x, y, z)
```

This ran in 135 time, about 4x slower than the simpler lookup

**Question 2:** Is there any way to speed up the lookups that I have here so that I can give my users more options?

I'd love to have more granularity so that users who just want a quick-and-dirty logging solution can write something easy like the latter two cases I showed (or even slower, just have a nullimpotent .log function on the fast path), but for critical sections of code where performance matters, I would love to have something which executes at a speed somewhere between the first case and the second case.

Comment: Are you autogenerating code here or is someone manually writing if foo: etc?

Comment: I think the only thing that would be faster than a boolean check is possibly a try/except.  When there's no exception, these are very fast, but if it catches an exception, they are very slow.

Comment: Even if that `if` was the entire content of your loop, it's hard to imagine how you could see a 32.5x slowdown.

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE demonstrating this incredible slowdown?

Comment: Maybe do `logger.log = lambda x, y, z: pass` if you don't want logging

Comment: I don't think the lambda expression would be a good idea. I'm 90 percent sure it would create a new stackframe, and I'm fairly certain that is much slower to do than just checking a conditional boolean. EDIT: I retract my 90 percent sure and now I'm 30 percent sure lol...I don't know what happens on pass.

Comment: Usually the short story is: if speed matters so much that the execution time of a boolean test makes a difference, using python is not the right choice.

Comment: Its the cost of building the local function environment, not the name lookup that is expensive. The conditional is fastest, even faster than `flag or logger.log(...)`.

Comment: @spectras That I typically agree with.  I'm targeting a bit of a special case here.  The workflow this particular software is built for involves writing code in python (for ease of development), then smoothly porting the performance parts to C.  However, there are cases where the business environment benefits from delaying that transition (more people know python), so I want a system that will continue to meet needs, even if some python code starts to act more and more performance critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `__debug__` variable and optimize the python execution when logging isn't important:

```
def log(x, y):
    print(x, y)


def doit():
    a = range(100)
    sum_ = 0

    for item1 in a:
        for item2 in a:
            if __debug__:
                log(item1, item2)
            sum_ += item1 + item2
    return sum_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit()
```

If you run this script as `python testscript.py` then it `prints` all this stuff. If you call it as `python -O testscripy.py` then it doesn't print anything because [`-O`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O) removes all `__debug__` parts.

Timings:

```
$ python -O -m timeit "from testscript1 import doit" "doit()"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 msec per loop
```

And if I remove the `if __debug__: log(item1, item2)` from the file it times as:

```
$ python -O -m timeit "from testscript2 import doit" "doit()"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.61 msec per loop
```

If I replace the `__debug__` with some custom variable this is definetly slower:

```
$ python -O -m timeit "from testscript3 import doit" "doit()"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.41 msec per loop
```